# I have a 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix. All of a sudden I'm having trouble keeping it on the road. It's like the wheels are not gripping the road

Tags: steering

I have a Pontiac Grand Prix 2004. All of a sudden I'm having trouble keeping it on the road. It's like the wheels are not gripping the road.

Comment: Easy stuff first. Have you checked the tire pressure in all four tires?

Comment: And check that you still have tread, if you've worn down your tires you won't get grip in wet conditions.